# Spring-data-mongodb : mongoTemplate - remove element from array in collection of documents

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Suppose I have a collection containing documents like :

```
{name: "a", preferences: ["apples","oranges","bananas"]}    
{name: "b", preferences: ["apricots","oranges","strawberries"]}
{name: "c", preferences: ["oranges","plums"]}
{name: "d", preferences: ["apples","plums","oranges"]}
{name: "e", preferences: ["strawberries","bananas"]}
```

Now there are no more **oranges** so I want to remove them from all documents and end up with :

```
{name: "a", preferences: ["apples","bananas"]}    
{name: "b", preferences: ["apricots","strawberries"]}
{name: "c", preferences: ["plums"]}
{name: "d", preferences: ["apples","plums"]}
{name: "e", preferences: ["strawberries","bananas"]}
```

I've been banging my head to know whether, using **Spring's mongoTemplate**, there is any straightforward way to do this, apart from the obvious (and, I guess, inefficient as the collection is potentially huge) iterative way ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried, can you put the code in?

Comment: You can try 
        `Update update = new Update();
        update.pull("preferences", "oranges");
        mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(), update, collection_name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do

```
Update update = new Update();
new Update().pull("preferences", "oranges");
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("preferences").elemMatch(Criteria.where("oranges").exists(true));// Use this if you don't want to do the above update for all documents.

mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(criteria), update, "collection_name");
```

Comment: This actually does not work. The elemMatch function can be used only when the array contain objects. When the array contains plain strings it should be Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("preferences").all("oranges");